# Can anyone suggest an Economical way for Polishing wound Wires?

Tags: mechanical, surface-preparation, polishing, manufacturing

I am working as a mechanical design engineer. At my work place, we were making chairs with 12 mm diameter wire via bending. We were using mild steel flash wires which was like the perfect wire with almost 0 to minor roughness. Recently because of the new regulations they have stopped the production of these wires. So our company is struggling to get the exact finish as before.

Our company was thinking of planetary polishing of the wires and then bending it to the part.

But in mind I was not completely happy with this method, so I thought of raising this query in this community.

1. I was thinking of something similar to lathe turning process but here the tool will be rotating. (I know it will be a slow process and mostly not possible.)
2. Somehow heating the wire to heat treat and make the surface finish higher.

I welcome any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Metals are drawn to produce wires.  You'd essentially start production of the wires you need.  You can certainly draw it through something that might produce the needed finish, including heating and rotating.  What is making you unhappy with planetary? It seems like your #1.  I suggest you remove the word wounded from your title...

Comment: I'd check with suppliers to see if you can't just get wire with the finish you want.  You may strike out -- but it makes sense to me that a supplier would have multiple customers that all want shiny wire.

Comment: I would get a few pieces of "wire" 1-2 meters long and experiment. Try pulling it through a forming die for example.